Normalizer of an $A$-invariant Sylow $p$-subgroup
I was reading the Antionio Beltrán and Changguo Shao article On the number of invariant Sylow subgroups under coprime action and there is a part of the Lemma 2.5. which I do not undertand.
First of all, at the end of section 1.Introduction, and before the statement of the lemmas, it is said that "All groups are supposed to be finite".
"Lemma 2.5. Let $A$ be a group acting coprimely on a solvable group $G$ and let $M$ be an $A$-invariant subgroup of $G$. Let $P$ be an $A$-invariant Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ with $P\leq M$, then $\nu^A_p(M)$ divides $\nu^A_p(G)$."
And in the Case 1 of the Lemma 2.5. it is said that "(...) By the Frattini argument, $G = N\mathbf{N}_G(P) = MN\mathbf{N}_G(P)$. By applying Lemma 2.1, $C = (C\cap N)(C\cap M)\mathbf{N}_C(P)$. (...)" Where $C=\mathbf{C}_G(A)$ and $N$ is a maximal $A$-invariant normal subgroup of $G$.
And "Lemma 2.1. Suppose that the action of a group $A$ on a the group $G$ is coprime. Let $G$ be the product of two $A$-invariant subgroups $X$ and $Y$. Then $\mathbf{C}_G(A) = \mathbf{C}_X(A)\mathbf{C}_Y(A)$."
My question is that I cannot see why $\mathbf{N}_G(P)$ is an $A$-invariant subgroup (implied by Lemma 2.1.).
What I have tried is: given that for all $a\in A$, $\alpha_a:G\to G$ with $\alpha_a(g)=g\cdot a$ is a bijection. It would be enough to show that for all $a\in A$, $n\in\mathbf{N}_G(P)$, we have that $n\cdot a\in\mathbf{N}_G(P)$ or, in other words, $P^{n\cdot a}=(n\cdot a)P(n\cdot a)^{-1}=P$. But, as said, I do not know how to continue.
Thanks in advance.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869317303988

Thanks for the answer, @NickyHekster! But, since the action of $A$ on $G$ is an arbitrary action, and not necessarily the action by conjugation, why does $aPa^{-1}=P\cdot a$ (that is what I think you have done)? And why should it be compatible with the group multiplication?

Let me write it in a different way: $P^{na}=(P^n)^a=P^a=P$, since $P$ ia $A$-invariant. By the way, the conjugation with elements of $A$ can be viewed with the semi direct product $G \rtimes A$.
